# Writing the correct path in fprintf function

Tags: c, file, printf, filepath, file-handling

Apparently, there's no data regarding my question (I tried searching it out here but none of the threads I've read answered my doubt). Here it is: I'm trying desperately to figure out how can I put a correct path into the fprintf function and none of my tries have been successful. Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
FILE *fp = NULL;

//opening the file
fp = fopen("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/myfile.txt", "w+");

//if there's an error when opening the file, the program shuts down
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("error");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//print something on the file the program just opened (or created if not already existent)
fprintf(fp, "to C or not to C, that is the question");

//closing the file
fclose(fp);

//end of main function
return 0;
}
```

My question is: why my program always shuts down? What am I doing wrong? It's just a Windows problem (I saw that, on the User1 folder icon, there's a lock, could be a permission denied thing?) or I'm just putting the path in an incorrect way? I tried to use a string to save the path, I tried to change the opening mode, I even tried to disable all the antiviruses, antimalwares and firewalls I have installed on my computer but nothing, the program still doesn't create the file where I want it.

P.S. Sorry for bad English.
P.P.S. Sorry if a similar question has been already posted, I didn't manage to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`perror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html) to have the Operating System help you determine the cause of failure.

```
#define FILENAME "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/myfile.txt"

    fp = fopen(FILENAME, "w+");

    // report and shut down on error
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror(FILENAME);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: It worked! The problem was that, since my computer's interface is in Italian, the path I wrote was incorrect because I translated the name's folder (in Italian users is translated into "Utenti", so the path was C:/Utenti/User1/Desktop). I wrote the path in English and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
fp = fopen("C:\Users\User1\Desktop\myfile.txt", "w+");
```

The character `\` is the **escape** character in C. You must escape it:

```
fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\myfile.txt", "w+");
```

Even better, windows now supports the `/` directory separator. So you can write:

```
fp = fopen("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/myfile.txt", "w+");
```

With no need to escape the path.

#### Reference:

[MSDN fopen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx), specifically the *Remaks* section

Comment: My mistake, I wrote down the program wrong, but in the editor I use I actually used \\, sorry for wasting your time!